# why are tfs_warehouse objects encrypted?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, encryption, tfs

Many of the objects (not data) in the tfs_warehouse database are encrypted ootb.

See the list of encrypted objects here:
    use tfs_warehouse
    go
    select o.xtype,c.encrypted,o.crdate,o.name from sys.syscomments c join sysobjects o
    on o.id = c.id
    order by 2 desc, 1 asc, 4 asc

It is not easy to see any pattern as to what is encrypted and what is not. The implication of this is that you cannot see the definition of these procs and views.

Why are these objects encrypted in the first place? I can find no documentation and I cannot think of any good reason.

Thx

Comment: To force you to use the API instead of digging around in the database?

Comment: There is no API for the warehouse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that these procs and views are encrypted to protect Microsoft's IP.